# TextBox not display value after ComboBox onChange (WPF, C#, Binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-binding, combobox

I have UserControl contains ComboBox and TextBox:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbId" SelectionChanged="cmbId_SelectionChanged" />
 <TextBox x:Name="txb1" Visibility="Hidden" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I have loaded values to ComboBox:

```
  public MyDataView()
  {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyDBViewDataContext mydata = new MyDBViewDataContext();
            cmbId.ItemsSource = (from q in mydata.test_views
                                        select q.Id).ToList();
  }
```

When user select item on ComboBox, the TextBox should display value:

```
private void cmbId_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
            int myId = 0;
            Int32.TryParse(cmbId.Text, out myId);

            txb1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            MyDBViewDataContext myDataList = new MyDBViewDataContext();
            var queryAll = (from q in myDataList.test_views
                        where q.Id.Equals(myId)
                        select q);
 }
```

But it's not working. Something is missing or what I did wrong?

Comment: You are binding to a property called FirstName...where do you expect the name to come from?

Comment: What would you expect it to do?

Comment: You need to set `FirstName`, then you need to probably raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` event in the setter of `FirstName`

Comment: FirstName should be taken from "queryAll"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `Id` and `FirstName` are properties of your entity class, you could set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ComboBox` to an `IEnumerable<YourEntityType>` and bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the `FirstName` property of the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox`:

```
public MyDataView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyDBViewDataContext mydata = new MyDBViewDataContext();
    cmbId.ItemsSource = (from q in mydata.test_views
                         select q).ToList();
}

<ComboBox x:Name="cmbId" DisplayMemberPath="Id"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txb1" Visibility="Hidden" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=cmbId}" />
```

Then there is no need to handle the `SelectionChanged` event at all.

The other option would be to actually set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` in the event handler:

```
txb1.Text = var queryAll = (from q in myDataList.test_views
                    where q.Id.Equals(myId)
                    select q.FirstName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thank you, but how to into your first answer, make TextBox visible after combobox selection?

Comment: That's another issue really. You could use a style that sets the Visibility property based on the Text property. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: A DataGrid also has a SelectedItem property that you can bind to.

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.AutoName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=cmbId}" /> it's not working :/

Comment: Again; please ask a new question if you have Another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have binded your textbox with a property, but I can't see in your code whether you are setting your property. Your textbox will display the selected name when you set your property to the selected item.